# Meaning of the "version" in any extension XML manifest file

Tags: xml, module

I'm new to Joomla! extension development, and I'm a little confused about the manifest XML file. What's the correct way to use these three `version` tags at the beginning of the XML file?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">`

`<version>1.0</version>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First version tag specifies the xml version.
Please refer [W3 standards for XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/)

Second version tag identifies the version of Joomla for which this extension is developed.

And third version stands for the version of this extension.

Refer [Joomla Manifest](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) for details.

Comment: Also note that won't need to change `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. It's only the other version numbers you will need to take into consideration ;)

Comment: So the `<extension version="2.5"...` is the _minimum_ version the extension will work in (as in 2.5 and above, including 3.x)? Can I specify an extension _only_ compatible with 2.5 and _not_ 3.x (pure curiosity...)?

Comment: Well it indicates the minimum joomla version supported by the extension. You can not specify not supported joomla version here.